# 【GA4】Why UTM parameters disappear after 24 hours?

Tags: google-analytics-4

This is about GA4's UTM parameters disappearing after 24 hours.

For example, after user A enters the site from a Google ad and leaves the site,

When he returns to the site three days later and converts, the UTM parameters have disappeared, so he cannot tell that the conversion was from Google Ads.

To solve this problem, it takes more effort to maintain a unique cookie and understand the initial inflow point.

Don't you think it would be better to extend the effectiveness of UTM parameters beyond 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

UTM parameters are a hack, essentially. Made to override other means to track channels. You don't track google ads with UTMs. Instead, you connect your analytics to your google ads. Here, [take a look](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9379420?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

The general idea of extending the effectiveness of UTM params is an odd one. Mostly because UTMs are ugly in how they utilize query params. You really don't want them to pop up everywhere. But also, query params are a piece of front-end functionality whose main role is facilitating the functionality of the site, so it's up to the site how the clear the params. Some site engines wouldn't even allow for unwarranted query parameters to populate, although that is a rarity.

How UTMs really persist by default is as a session. Once the session is expired, the value won't be backfilled. Usually people make it persist for longer via ETL and then backfilling, or I guess technically one could repopulate them via cookies and to avoid making the urls ugly, you could just override the dl dimension of tracking, adding query params there instead. But I've never seen anyone doing it and I've seen many odd analytics implementations.